# Generar tabla en vista mediante una consulta a la base de datos. JSON, JQUERY, MVC, .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Soy nueva en el foro y tengo todo el dia quebrandome la cabeza por no poder resolver esto. Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Tengo una aplicacion muy sencilla en c# .net. Necesito generar una tabla a partir de un json que (segun yo) contiene la informacion de una consulta a la base de datos (SQL SERVER). La tabla debe aparecer al hacer click sobre otra tabla principal que esta en la vista; de ahi agarra el ID para hacer la consulta a la BD. Estoy intentando generar la tabla con jquery, la otra tabla se genera automaticamente con el modelo (Entity Framework). 
Espero haber sido especifica, aqui les dejo parte de mi codigo a ver si se entiende un poco mejor la idea:

**MODELO**

```
public class ApCommentView
{
    [Key]
    public int id_comment { get; set; }
    public int id_app { get; set; }
    public string version_app { get; set; }
    public string comentario { get; set; }
}
```

**MANAGER**

```
public class ApCommentManager
{
    LogBDEntities1 bd = new LogBDEntities1();

    public List<app_comments> idSearch(int id_ap)
    {
        var result = from c in bd.app_comments where
                     c.id_app.Equals(id_ap)
                     select c;

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(int id)
    {
        ApCommentManager ACM = new ApCommentManager();
        var results = ACM.idSearch(id);
        return Json(results);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
    function BUSCARid() {
    var tr = $('#dataApp').find('tr');
    tr.bind('click', function (event) {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var id_app = row.find("td:eq(0)").html().trim();
       alert(id_app);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Search","Home")',
            data: { id : id_app },
            success: function () {
                alert("OK");

        $("#resultado").html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#resultado").append("<li> " + result[i].id_app + " " + result[i].version_app + " " + result[i].comentario + " </li>");
        //}
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        //debugger;
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        alert("Error has occurred..");
    }
        });
    });
});
```

PD: La vista donde quiero generar la tabla hace referencia al modelo de donde sale la tabla principal, no se si eso afecte en algo.

Comment: Te funciona el `alert(id_app);`?

Comment: Si si me funciona, creo que el problema esta ya en el controlador o en la parte de successs donde quiero generar la tabla. Incluso ayer me funicono hasta el alert("OK") en la parte de success; pero no me genero nada

Answer (score 2):

La solución te la han dado en la respuesta de arriba. Te explico que ocurre.

En tu controller estas devolviendo los results, que son una lista de objetos app_comment, a través de un función de retorno Json(). Esta te formateará los objetos a un string de formato JSON que tu código JS es capaz de interpretar, sin embargo, le tienes que decir qué nombre de variable le vas a otorgar si la solicitud es correcta.

```
success: function(results){
    //Aquí la variable results es la lista en formato json de tus objetos app_comment.
    //results[0] sería tu primer objeto de la lista.
    //TODO
}
```

---

Pero si en vez de results, le llamaras wololo, lo podrías usar igualmente, es como si en el momento de hacer la llamada de success asignaras a la variable de entrada a la function el valor que te devuelve la llamada al controlador. Por tanto esto sería así:

```
success: function(wololo){
    //Aquí la variable wololo es la lista en formato json de tus objetos app_comment.
    //wololo[0] sería tu primer objeto de la lista.
    //TODO
}
```

La llamada Ajax no es capaz de asignar el valor de retorno de la llamada a la URL a una variable por defecto, así que le tenemos que dar un nombre para que funcione. Lo mismo sería si fuese un error. Pero así:

```
success: function(wololo){
    //Aquí la variable wololo es la lista en formato json de tus objetos app_comment.
    //wololo[0] sería tu primer objeto de la lista.
    //TODO
},
error: function(wololo){
    //En cambio aquí la variable wololo es el objeto error que devuelve el ajax.
    alert(wololo); //Mostrará en un alert el error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu ajax, agrega el parametro de respuesta en el success. Aparentemente todo esta ok.

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Search","Home")',
            data: { id : id_app },
            success: function (result) {//aquí
                alert("OK");

        $("#resultado").html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#resultado").append("<li> " + result[i].id_app + " " + result[i].version_app + " " + result[i].comentario + " </li>");
        }
    },
```

Comment: Como que el parametro de respuesta? Es que soy nueva en esto

Comment: Como en el controlador estas regresando un Json de respuesta, el ajax debe de tener un parametro que lo regrese. En este caso en el success. Estoy hablando de la linea  =>  success: function (result)